# Use of be+infinitive in different meanings

Tags: infinitives, imperative-sentences

I know that `be + infinitive` is used for order, instruction and plan but some of the example sentences are confusing to me they are:

> 1. I'm to go now. ( what's the meaning of this sentence ?)
> 2. Mr johns was to speak at the meeting last monday. ( if this sentence is about past plan, was the plan fulfilled ? Or what's the meanings of this sentence ?)
> 3. You are to be on time.(what kind of meaning this sentence implies?)
> 4. Am I to believe what they say ? ( what kind of meaning this sentence conveys ?)
>      Now, if the meaning of those sentences is similar to 'supposed to', why be+infini' is used instead of supposed to' ? Is 'supposed to' is the same as 'should' or what?
>      I'm expecting understandable answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Be + to-infinitive is used to express:

1. Official arrangements or plans:

> We are to meet at his office at six.
>
> The Prime Minister is to visit Poland next week.

2. Orders and obligations:

> At the end of the course, all students are to take a written exam.
>
> You are to do your homework before you go to the cinema.

3. Things that should be done:

> What am I to do?
>
> You are to stay here until I send for you.

4. A possible aim when saying what should be done to reach it:

> If you are to work here for more than three months, you must have a
>   residence permit.

5. What is fated to happen:

> I met a girl who was to become a queen.

6. Pre-conditions:

> If we are to get there on time we had better hurry.

7. Prohibition (in the negative):

> You are not to do that again.

In your examples # 1 is a prohibition, # 2 is an order, # 3 is what should be done, # 4 is a fulfilled plan (otherwise it were to be "*to have spoken*"), # 5 is an order, and # 6 is asking about whether something should be or is obligatory to be done.

Regarding obligations, the use of *"must"* expresses the strong ones and  usually means that some personal circumstance makes the obligation necessary,  and for this reason the speaker almost certainly agrees with the obligation, whereas *to be + to-infinitive* shows that the obligation is/has to be just put up with no matter what the speaker thinks about it.

> You are to return to the regiment by 10 p.m. (a comander's order)
>
> I was to execute the deserter and I did it.( I was ordered to, and
>   orders are peromptory)
>
> He is your brother. You must help him. (it's your moral obligation).
>
> I must stop him before it's too late. (I feel it must be done. Why not
>   by me?)

The source: Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, Third Edition, Oxford University Press, ISBN-13: 9780194420969, p.80, para 91

Comment: I'm afraid to say, No answers have fully addressed my all questions, could you please answer what i'm asking

Comment: Answerer should be aware what op is asking in his question

Comment: yubraj sharma@ A para added

Comment: It would be better if you could provide examples to make the answer understandable. I'm merly a English learner so I should go through contextual examples to understand the meanings, because grammar is understood better with examples. As you know "example is better than preach"

Comment: yubraj sharma@ Done

Comment: Rompey@ sir, you shouldn't have used complex words. What is the meaning of deserter, peromptory and regiment ?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can replace *I'm to* with *I'm **supposed** to*. In some, it will have the stronger sense of an **obligation** as you noticed in 1. and 2.

> 3. I'm to go now.
>
>    I'm **supposed to** go now / I should be going now.

In 4.:

> 4. Mr Johns was to speak at the meeting last monday.
>
>    Mr Johns was **supposed to** speak at the meeting last monday.

Which, in a sense, implies that he didn't.

Since you added 2 sentences, same story:

> 5. You are to be on time.
>
>    You are **supposed to** be on time.

Which here, sounds more like a judgement, a scolding from your boss because you were late.
And:

> 6. Am I to believe what they say ?
>
>    Am I **supposed to** believe what they say ?

The context will help you guess if it is a strict obligation or not, as you already did for the first two sentences.

Comment: I've already told that I don't know the meaning of 'supposed to' itself. I'm expecting understandable answer

Comment: You didn't say that before the edits, and I'm not some kind of divinity which can read stackexchange users' minds.
**Supposed to** = **Expected to**, does that help ?

Comment: I would say 'yes' that helps a bit

Comment: I'm afraid to say, No answers have fully addressed my all questions yet, could you please answer what i'm asking,

Comment: And what about my other questions? 'Must' and 'be+infin. ? . . . Haven't been addressed yet