# Clarification about this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs, sentence-usage

> Then, over the course of a century or two, they (the aforementioned towns) emptied out (in much the same way as the Natchez Great Village was later **to do** [...]

As you might have guessed by the bold text, my question is about the meaning of 'to do'.
I understand that the Natchez Great Village emptied out like the aforementioned towns, only at a later time.

My question is, would the sentence have been the same if written this way?

> Then, over the course of a century or two, they (the aforementioned towns) emptied out (in much the same way as the Natchez Great Village later **did** [...]

If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: [related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91491/meaning-of-a-sentence-with-was-to)

Comment: At the time the writer is talking about, the 'emptying' of the Natchez Great Village was still in the future - it is being viewed from the perspective of those times.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. As explained in the related question that xyldke added a link to, 'To do' also denotes a sense of destiny or imminence, at least in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Be to X* = *will/would X* with an implication that there is a requirement that X is done - e.g. "X is to Y" means something is making/requiring/forcing X to do Y.

> You are to go to the store at 3pm = You will go to the store at 3pm.

> The grandfather attended college just as the son was to do = The grandfather attended college just as the son would do.

So you cannot replace *was later to do* with *later did* as it removes the implication that something forced X to do it.

> Then, over the course of a century or two, they (the aforementioned towns) emptied out (in much the same way as the Natchez Great Village was later to do [...]

This is saying the village emptied out due to a condition making/requiring/forcing it to empty out.

@Fra says this in the comments:

> 'To do' also denotes a sense of destiny or imminence

and if something will happen due to destiny/imminence - it's basically going to "make" you do it, so *to do X* can express that.